# How to create a histogram with different space between the bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a histogram with four pairs of bars as following. How to do it?[image]

Comment: Maybe you could provide some test data, the code you tried, and an explanation of what type of histogram you want to create. What do the letters mean?  How is this a histogram and not just a bar plot? ...?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do a dual bar histogram with *matplotlib* and *numpy* libraries.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
X = ['A','B','C','D']
left_values = [35,25,10,8] # Left bar values
right_values = [40,30,15,12] # Right bar values

# Setting X Axis range
x_axis = np.arange(len(X))

# -0.2 and +0.2 to separate the two bars
plt.bar(x_axis - 0.2, left_values, 0.4)
plt.bar(x_axis + 0.2, right_values, 0.4)
  
plt.xticks(x_axis, X)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output graph]

Have a good day.